# How to merge child object with Parent object when used in async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to merge child Object **rawData** with parent, I used below code and it works perfectly fine.

But the issue arises when I fetch from MongoDB & use it using async/await, it doesn't and return only the same original source as output.
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var source = await Project.find({})
```

```js
var source = [
    {
        "_id": "5f6b3f9c24b38656ec43ui38",
        "Term": "Term B",
        
        "rawData": {
            "Plants1_growTime": 0,
            "Plants1_sunTime": 10,
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f508e8427e8824ad8f055dd",
        "Term": "Term B",
        "rawData": {
            "Plants1_growTime": 34,
            "Plants1_sunTime": 65,
        }
    }
]

 source.forEach(function (item) {
    var rawData = item.rawData;
    delete item.rawData;
    for (var property in rawData) {
      item[property] = rawData[property];
    }
  });
  
  console.log(source);
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code about the "fetch from MongoDB & use it using async/await" apart

Comment: Thanks, I used simply var source = await Project.find({}). I get all the two records which used static in variable source. While Project is my model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const cursor = await Project.find({});

const source = cursor.toArray()
```

find will return a cursor, please see:

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve#find

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray

Comment: I received this error message "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: source.toArray is not a function". My source is array itself, when I do soruce.length, it returns 2

Comment: Could you paste the code for better understand what going on?
Maybe paste in codepen or codesandbox
if I can see the code from async part to merge part